# Visual Studio 2013 missing publish/deployment options

Tags: c#, azure, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

I'm unable to create a .zip deployment package for an MVC app because Visual Studio's Publish wizard is missing the option to choose different publishing profile or publish targets. The only option visible and selectable is the "Microsoft Azure Virtual Machines".

Here is a screenshot of the publish window:

[image]

What can be the cause of this? I recently installed some Azure related SDKs, so that might have something to do with it, but I'd still expect to see the old options also..

Comment: What is the exact version of the visual studio? Have you tried to reset settings? Thats my first option for everything vs related though not so wise. You can reset by running devenv /resetsettings

Comment: VS2013.4 Ultimate (12.0.31101.00 exactly). I tried both /ResetSettings and /ResetUserData to no avail